# Indexing query in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I'm trying to index this query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE t.title, na.name, na.gender, cn.name
FROM title t JOIN cast_info ci ON t.id = ci.movie_id
JOIN name na ON ci.person_id = na.id
JOIN char_name cn ON ci.person_role_id = cn.id
JOIN movie_info_idx m ON t.id = m.movie_id
WHERE ci.nr_order < 3
AND t.kind_id = 1
AND m.info_type_id = 112
AND m.info < 11
AND ci.role_id IN (1,2)
ORDER BY m.info ASC;
```

Without index it's 0.77 sec. I've done this index:

```
CREATE INDEX index3_m ON movie_info_idx(movie_id, info_type_id, info(20));
CREATE INDEX index3_t ON title(kind_id, title(30));
CREATE INDEX index3_ci ON cast_info(movie_id, nr_order, role_id);
```

Now it's 13.48 sec. So, I'm doing something wrong. My idea was to order movie_info_idx and cast_info to make it easier for the title to access...
Here is the database:
[image]

Thanks for the help.

EDIT: I add what the query is for: List of films in the top 10 with the name of their main actors / actresses (nr_order <3), if it is an actor or actress and the name of the character they play in the film. Sort the result by the ranking in the top 10 of the movie.

EDIT 2: The explain result:
[image]

Comment: Can you add `explain` response for your query?

Comment: @Flying Yes there it goes

Comment: Actually I mean: run `explain select ... rest of your query ...` and update your question with result of this statement. It will contain information about how your query will be executed by SQL server

Comment: @Flying ok sorry, I didn't understood you. Done

Comment: You have over 500k rows to sort because of `title` table, it is a reason of slowness. Do you see by yourself any conditions that can be applied to this table to reduce amount of fetched information?

Comment: One of the reason can be your `index3_t` index that includes `title`. It is unlikely need to have multi-column indexes here, it may be worth to split indexes to have separate index for each column

Comment: It may also be worth to create sub-query to fetch top 10 films and then use join by this sub-query into main query to fetch actors. It will dramatically reduce amount of information to process

Comment: The `EXPLAIN` says that the Optimizer decided that it was best to start with `t`.  My answer, among other things, provides an index that will get the Optimizer to start with `m`, where I think things will be much more efficient.  That is, don't focus on the index for `t`, focus on getting the table order correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Index prefixing is rarely valuable.

That query needs this index on `movie_info_idx`:

```
INDEX(info_type_id, info)
```

in *this* order, and without prefixing.

For further discussion, please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` (the diagram does not provide datatypes, nor indexes) and `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` (to see where it is going sour).

**Further analysis**

First, let me rearrange the `JOINs` and `ANDs` to match the order that is *probably* best:

```
SELECT  SQL_NO_CACHE t.title, na.name, na.gender, cn.name
    FROM  movie_info_inx m
    JOIN  title t  ON t.id = m.movie_id              -- t: (id)
    JOIN  cast_info ci  ON t.id = ci.movie_id        -- ci: (movie_id)
    JOIN  name na  ON ci.person_id = na.id           -- na: (id)
    JOIN  char_name cn  ON ci.person_role_id = cn.id -- cn: (id)
    WHERE  m.info_type_id = 112
      AND  m.info < 11            -- m: (info_type_id, info)
      AND  t.kind_id = 1          -- t: (kind_id, id)  -- either order
      AND  ci.nr_order < 3
      AND  ci.role_id IN (1,2)    -- ci: (movie_id, then either nr_order or role_id)
    ORDER BY  m.info ASC;         -- included above
```

I annotated it with likely indexes.

Nothing useful for "covering" if `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` for `cn`, `na`.  However, this could be useful for `ci`:

```
 INDEX(movie_id, nr_order, role_id) -- `movie_id` first
```

Summary:  Add these indexes:

```
m: (info_type_id, info)
t: (kind_id, id)  -- either order
ci:  (movie_id, nr_order, role_id)  -- `movie_id` first
```

Comment: There you have the explain, it's difficult to do the "show create.." as there are four tables there but if you need it I will do it. To be clear: should I use also the other two index?

Comment: I added 3 indexes that you need for _this_ query.  Other indexes may (or may not) be useful for other queries.  I assume `id` is the `PRIMARY KEY` in any table having `id`.  (If it is not, then I need to make further revisions.)

Comment: Yeah, id is the PRIMARY KEY in all of them that have it. I'm going to prove it, it's going to take some time, I'll comment when I have it. Thanks

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela - One pitfall you may have:  Don't blindly use `TEXT` if a `VARCHAR` of less than 255 will suffice.  There are optimizations (especially in indexes) that cannot be done with `TEXT`.

Comment: Thanks for the advice Rick. The query now takes 12.71 secs... What do you think about it?

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela - Hmmm...  Let's see the new EXPLAIN.

Comment: @JaimeAlcántaraArnela - how fast is it now?